# How do i customize data returned when using Doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3 and Doctrine and have entities and relationships setup and have my controller returning:

```
  {
  "retrieved": "2016-06-30T16:47:49+0200",
  "currentPage": "1",
  "totalItems": "3",
  "itemsPerPage": "50",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "tasktitle": "This is the first task",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\",
      "duedate": "2016-12-25T23:59:59+0100",
      "dateadded": "2016-06-20T16:43:06+0200",
      "projectid": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PM Tool",
        "dateadded": "2016-06-20T16:43:06+0200",
        "createdbyuserid": {
          "id": 1,
          "firstname": "test",
          "lastname": "test"
        },
        "userid": []
      },
      "taskstatus": {
        "id": 1,
        "taskstatus": "Not Started"
      },
      "priority": {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": "Urgent"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "tasktitle": "Code this beast",
      "description": "This project is going to be sweet.",
      "duedate": "2016-12-26T23:59:59+0100",
      "dateadded": "2016-06-20T16:43:06+0200",
      "projectid": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PM Tool",
        "dateadded": "2016-06-20T16:43:06+0200",
        "createdbyuserid": {
          "id": 1,
          "firstname": "test",
          "lastname": "test"
        },
        "userid": []
      },
      "taskstatus": {
        "id": 9,
        "taskstatus": "Completed"
      },
      "priority": {
        "id": 3,
        "priority": "Medium"
      }
    }        
  ]
}
```

However this is way more information than i need for my front-end.  I do not need the entire dataset from the related tables and would like something like this:

```
{
  "retrieved": "2016-06-30T16:47:49+0200",
  "currentPage": "1",
  "totalItems": "3",
  "itemsPerPage": "50",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "tasktitle": "This is the first task",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\",
      "duedate": "2016-12-25T23:59:59+0100",
      "dateadded": "2016-06-20T16:43:06+0200",
      "projectname": "PM Tool",       
      "taskstatus": "Not Started",
      "priority": "Urgent"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "tasktitle": "Code this beast",
      "description": "This project is going to be sweet.",
      "duedate": "2016-12-26T23:59:59+0100",
      "dateadded": "2016-06-20T16:43:06+0200",
      "projectid": "PM Tool",       
      "taskstatus": "Completed"
      "priority": "Medium"      
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone help me wrap my head around the Symfony way of doing this?

Comment: What returns that json code? Or is that just a dump() in twig?

Comment: $tasks = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Task')->findBy(
            array(), 
            array('id' => 'ASC'), //order by
            $count, 
            ($page - 1) * $count // offset
        );
$tasks = $query->getResult(); 
        
        $data = [
            'retrieved' => $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'),
            'currentPage' => $page,
            'totalItems' => $total,
            'itemsPerPage' => $count,
            'tasks' => $tasks
        ];        
        $view->setData($data)->setStatusCode(200);        
        return $view;

Comment: If you've got more data than you need, then why not just create your own array and transform into json. And no offense to anyone but with Symfony supposedly having such a huge community of supporters, experts, and so on who surely would have come up with an issue like this or similar before, why then can no one answer this seemingly easy question? Ive asked a question 3 times in 3 different ways with no direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten the below code to work well for what i'm trying to do.  Not really sure if it's the ideal way or not?  If you have any further recommendations please let me know.

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT t.id as TaskId, 
                                              t.tasktitle as TaskTitle,
                                              ts.taskstatus as TaskStatus, 
                                              p.name as ProjectName, 
                                              c.clientname as Cient, 
                                               IDENTITY(t.jobnumber) as Jobnumber, 
                                              t.duedate as DueDateTime,
                                              t.lastupdated as LastUpdated,
                                              IDENTITY(p.accesstypeid) as AccessType,
                                              (SELECT IDENTITY(s.userid) FROM AppBundle:Subscriber s WHERE s.taskid = t.id AND s.isowner = true) as Owner
                                        FROM AppBundle:Task t 
                                        JOIN t.projectid p
                                        LEFT JOIN p.clientid c
                                        JOIN t.taskstatus ts
                                        LEFT JOIN t.jobnumber j
                                        WHERE
                                        ( ?1 IS NULL OR t.duedate < ?1)
                                        AND (LENGTH(?2) = 0 OR p.id = ?2 )
                                        AND (LENGTH(?3) = 0  OR c.id = ?3)
                                        AND (ts.taskstatus != 'Completed' AND ts.taskstatus != 'Deleted')
                                        ")
                                        ->setFirstResult($offset)
                                        ->setMaxResults(50);

            $query->setParameter(1,$duefiltervalue);
            $query->setParameter(2,$projectfilter);
            $query->setParameter(3,$clientfilter);
            $tasks = $query->getResult(); 

            $data = [
                'retrieved' => $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'),
                'currentPage' => $page,
                'totalItems' => $total,
                'itemsPerPage' => $count,
                'tasks' => $tasks
            ];

            $view->setData($data)->setStatusCode(200);

            return $view;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMS Serializer to use annotations if you use an API. 
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
    use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
    use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

```
/**
 * Book
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */

class Book
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Groups({"book"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"book"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $isbn;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"book"})
     * @Expose
     */
    private $title;
```

And in your controller get the specific group of data that you expose

```
/**
 * @View(serializerGroups={"book"})
 */
public function comingKoobAction($piBookId)
{
    $loManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    return $loManager->getRepository("AppBundle:Book")->find($piBookId);
}
```

Some documentation 
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle